# Как узнать об изменениях на сервере?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как узнать, что на сервере произошли изменения, желательно не обновляя весь список?

Есть программа, которая подключена к sql серверу... Возник вопрос, если один пользователь запустил определённую часть данных, а через секунду другой пользователь изменил данные на сервере, которые загрузил пользователь номер 1, и чтоб у пользователя номер 1 эти изменения сразу же отобразились (подобное, как в google docs на документах и таблицах).

Просто подумал сначала, чтоб, например, каждые X секунд делать обновления, и тогда если есть что-то новое, то оно отобразится, но как-то это не очень разумно и нагрузка и на сервер, и на клиент. Как это вообще в "жизни" делается, чтоб "сказать" программе пользователя номер 1, что там-то и там-то изменились данные и что надо обновиться?

Comment: А что-то типа observer'а можно организовать?

Comment: @rasmisha `Observer` в системах с базами данных - это обычно плохая идея, поскольку это нерационально для большого количества клиентов. Лучше делать это по `pull`-принципу.

Comment: Спасибо, просто не знал :) учту, если самому что делать такое придется

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Частица то всегда пишется через дефис.

Comment: Спасибо, учту )))))))

Answer (score 1):

- При каждом обновлении данных на сервере записывать в базу данных `Timestamp` последнего обновления и получать его в результатах запроса. Далее - можно действительно раз в `X` секунд спрашивать последний `Timestamp` у сервера, и, *если он новее, чем `Timestamp` на клиенте,* то подгружать изменения.
- Разумеется, что в случае, если данные не `read-only`, то для работоспособности такого решения вам придется обдумать стратегию разрешения конфликтов *(по типу того, как это делают системы контроля версий).*
- [`MySql TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Ну не очень понятно... можно пример... есть таблица `ID_Stud, ID_Disciplini, Ocenka` и там, скажем, 10 тысяч строк, и просто непонятно, что загружать во временную таблицу.

Comment: Или там просто время последнего обновления записывать? Тогда с другой стороны, если один пользователь отредактировал фрагмент 1, а другой загрузил фрагмент 2, то зачем обновлять?